# How to do a weekly refresh for R shiny data

Tags: r, shiny, cron

I have an app deployed on shinyapps.io . It reads off a CSV  in the global.R that is created from another r script that pulls data from various databases and merges and cleans the data. How can I refresh the CSV and republish the app on a weekly basis so the data is refreshed? I’m building this for a client, so I don’t want it run locally.

Comment: set up a cron job to run a `update_data.R` script to make a new .csv file. I am pretty sure shiny will load the csv file for each new connection, so the app will use the new data as it becomes available.

Comment: Is there a way to automate republishing the R Shiny app?   The app won’t be run locally (maybe run on Shiny Server)

Comment: When you say it's run on "Shiny Server", do you mean the hosted service (shinyapps.io) or your own server running shiny server?

Comment: It is run on shinyapps.io

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure. Maybe update the file locally, then host it somewhere that your app can access it.

Comment: I can't speak to scheduling/refreshing the data on shinyapps.io but there's a package called `simpleCache` that I've used in the past that has been helpful for refreshing when the data gets stale.  Good luck.